# JsPlumb flowchart division alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsplumb

I am creating a flow chart using JPlumb and Jquery. I have created a flow but there is an alignment issue with division. I am sharing my code through JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jPLd/87/)

```
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
var fillColor = "gray";
jsPlumb.Defaults.Connector = [ "Flowchart", { stub:40 } ];
jsPlumb.Defaults.DragOptions = { cursor: "pointer", zIndex:2000 };
jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle = { strokeStyle:"#2E9AFE", lineWidth:3 };
jsPlumb.Defaults.EndpointStyle = { radius:4, fillStyle:"gray" };
jsPlumb.Defaults.Anchors =  [ "BottomCenter", "TopCenter" ];

var overlays = [
[ "Arrow", { location:1 }]
];

    jsPlumb.connect({source:"window1", target:"window3"});
    jsPlumb.connect({source:"window2", target:"window3"});
    jsPlumb.draggable($(".window"));

});
```

The alignment should be like this [Division Alignment](http://pbrd.co/JEDOHj)

[image]

Comment: jsfiddle link is picture link

Comment: both link is image only change the fiddle link

Comment: Hi I have edited and added the jsfiddle link ... Please help me to align the divisions with id window1,window2 and window3

Comment: reply please for this question